# Negation of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

My book states that an integral domain is a commutative ring with unity in which $1 \neq 0$ and there are no nonzero zero-divisors.

So if $R$ is not an integral domain, does that mean $R$ is a commutative ring with unity in which $1 = 0$ and there are nonzero zero-divisors?

Comment: Well, $R$ could not be an integral domain if the ring $R$ has no unity for example (since your definition requires it). But *usually* $R$ is not an integral domain if there is some non trivial zero divisor.

Comment: Well, in principle $R$ could be a rat. But the **tacit** universe here is probably commutative rings with unit, and *probably* with $0\ne 1$. So what is intended is probably only that there exist $a$, $b$, neither $0$, such that $ab=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. By [de Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), the negation of a ring being an integral domain is: either $0=1$ or there is a nonzero zero divisor (or both).

Comment: Ah I see what I missed. But if $R$ is not an integral domain, $R$ is still possibly a commutative ring with unity right?

Comment: @Student: That's right!